# How to get data from s3 and do some work on it? python and boto

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, boto, amazon-emr

I have a project task to use some output data I have already produced on s3 in an EMR task. So previously I have ran an EMR job that produced some output in one of my s3 buckets in the form of multiple files named part-xxxx. Now I need to access those files from within my new EMR job, read the contents of those files and by using that data I need to produce another output.

This is the local code that does the job:

```
def reducer_init(self):
        self.idfs = {}
        for fname in os.listdir(DIRECTORY): # look through file names in the directory
            file = open(os.path.join(DIRECTORY, fname)) # open a file
            for line in file: # read each line in json file
                term_idf = JSONValueProtocol().read(line)[1] # parse the line as a JSON object
                self.idfs[term_idf['term']] = term_idf['idf']

    def reducer(self, term_poster, howmany):
        tfidf = sum(howmany) * self.idfs[term_poster['term']]
        yield None, {'term_poster': term_poster, 'tfidf': tfidf}
```

This runs just fine locally, but the problem is the data i need now is on s3 and i need to access it somehow in reducer_init function.

This is what I have so far, but it fails while executing on EC2:

```
def reducer_init(self):
self.idfs = {}
b = conn.get_bucket(bucketname)
idfparts = b.list(destination)
    for key in idfparts:
    file = open(os.path.join(idfparts, key))
    for line in file:
    term_idf = JSONValueProtocol().read(line)[1] # parse the line as a JSON object
            self.idfs[term_idf['term']] = term_idf['idf']

def reducer(self, term_poster, howmany):
    tfidf = sum(howmany) * self.idfs[term_poster['term']]
    yield None, {'term_poster': term_poster, 'tfidf': tfidf}
```

AWS access info is defined as follows:

```
awskey = '*********'
awssecret = '***********'
conn = S3Connection(awskey, awssecret)
bucketname = 'mybucket'
destination = '/path/to/previous/output'
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways of doing this :

1. Download the file into your local system and parse it. ( Kinda simple, quick and easy )
2. Get data stored on S3 into memory and parse it ( a bit more complex in case of huge files ).

Step 1:

On S3 filenames are stored as a Key, if you have a file named `"Demo"` stored in a folder named `"DemoFolder"` then the key for that particular file would be `"DemoFolder\Demo"`.

Use the below code to download the file into a temp folder.

```
AWS_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
AWS_SECRET_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
BUCKET_NAME = 'DemoBucket'
fileName = 'Demo'

conn = connect_to_region(Location.USWest2,aws_access_key_id = AWS_KEY,
            aws_secret_access_key = AWS_SECRET_KEY,
            is_secure=False,host='s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
            )
source_bucket = conn.lookup(BUCKET_NAME)

''' Download the file '''
for name in source_bucket.list():
        if name.name in fileName:
            print("DOWNLOADING",fileName)
            name.get_contents_to_filename(tempPath)
```

You can then work on the file in that temp path.

Step 2:

You can also fetch data as string using `data = name.get_contents_as_string()`. In case of huge files (> 1gb) you may come across memory errors, to avoid such errors you will have to write a lazy function which reads the data in chunks.

For example you can use `range` to fetch a part of file using `data = name.get_contents_as_string(headers={'Range': 'bytes=%s-%s' % (0,100000000)})`.

I am not sure if I answered your question properly, I can custom code for your requirement once I get some time. Meanwhile please feel free to post any query you have.

Comment: Can you tell me what after downloading?

Like I have an S3 file containing JSONs 
I want to parse those based on key value pairs maybe.. How do I use EMR to do that? What will be the script?